# "Welcome to Intellek" when trying to install Windows LTSC 2021 in Qemu

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, qemu

On the "Account" stage, it says "Welcome to Intellek" and prompts me to enter my email for Intellek. I do not know what that is, a search reveals it is some company? I downloaded two ISOs from the official Windows evaluation site. I do not know how to continue: [what I am presented with][2]

My qemu command:

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=Windows.img,format=qcow2,if=virtio \
 -drive file="en-us_windows_10_enterprise_ltsc_2021_x64_dvd_d289cf96.iso",media=cdrom -drive file=virtio-win.iso,media=cdrom \
 -boot order=d -enable-kvm -machine type=q35 -cpu host,hv_vpindex,hv_runtime,hv_synic,hv_stimer,hv_reset,hv-relaxed,hv-vapic,hv-spinlocks=0x1fff,hv-time \
 -m 32G -smp sockets=1,cores=6,threads=1 \
 -device virtio-vga-gl -display sdl,gl=on \
 -netdev user,id=network0 -device e1000,netdev=network0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:56
```

us_windows_10_enterprise_ltsc_2021_x64_dvd_d289cf96.iso
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ih0F.png

Comment: why would you download a Windows ISO from a dodgy site? Pull it from microsoft only. This is pretty off-topic honestly. Q - "Hey folks, looks like I downloaded something that's been tampered with, what do I do?" A - "Don't do that."

Comment: Seriously - this is clearly put up by someone trolling for people to get infected or their creds stolen.
https://isofiles.bd581e55.workers.dev/Windows%2010/Windows%2010%20Enterprise%20LTSC%202021/README.md
What could have possibly led to you trying to use this ISO link?

Comment: @mfinni In the post I said the checksums match, so it has not been tampered with. I checked both SHA1 and SHA256, plus even the official iso does this. It would be useful if you try to read the post. Thanks

Comment: You haven't actually showed that the checksums match. You came here asking for help - the answer is "don't use Windows ISOs from anywhere but Microsoft."

Comment: If the official ISO also does this, then the machine you're using to download it is likely compromised.

Comment: @mfinni Not compromised, I want to emphasize I am running it on QEMU

Comment: OK, cool, you're not compromised. Go ahead and put your creds right into that dialog box. I'm not sure why you're asking for help if you won't listen.

Comment: Hey - cool, I see you got the answer from Reddit, I was wrong. Autopilot and a UUID collision was the issue, I've learned something.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10LTSC/comments/1075anp/welcome_to_intellek/

That said, putting the weird Cloudfare ISO link into the question definitely muddied the waters.

Comment: @mfinni Yes, that is my reddit post. I figured out it is probably using a UUID. Sorry for being impudent in the comments. I guess this question can be moved to the new one I posted while this was closed.